# Why is seconds not converting to hours and days

Tags: python, django, datetime

I created a function to display how much time has elapsed, but for some reason the conditional statement does not return at specific statements after the first elif. Adding a print statement shows that the function is flowing however as objects are printed out. I am not sure why this is happening as the time elapsed since some posts were made are greater than 3600 seconds in elapsed time. It is therefore converting all elapsed time solely to minutes, but I will say that the time elapsed in seconds is working properly. Am I doing my conversion wrong or is it a syntax or type error? Also, is there a better way to go about this?

```
def time_diff(self):
    if self.date_pub:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
        diff = now - self.date_pub
        total_time = diff.total_seconds()
        if total_time < 60:
            return str(int(total_time)) + "s ago."
        elif total_time > 60 or total_time <= 3600:
            return str(int(total_time / 60)) + "m ago."
        elif total_time >= 3600 or total_time <= 86400:
            return str(int(total_time / 3600)) + "h ago."
        elif total_time >= 86400 or total_time <= 604800:
            return str(nt(total_time / 86400)) + "d ago."
        else:
            return date_pub
```

Comment: Did you use the debugger to step through the code? Also, why not use `timedelta` instead?

Comment: You might want to use [`django.contrib.humanize.naturaltime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up, you should fix the cases where you have gaps, such as `60` which will not be caught by *any* of the `if/elif` clauses. It should be `< 60` the `>= 60` in the first two condition checks.

Additionally, all of those `or` keywords should *definitely* be `and`. Think of what happens for a day (86,400 seconds):

```
elif total_time > 60 or total_time <= 3600:
    return str(int(total_time / 60)) + "m ago."
```

Since `86,400` is greater than `60`, this will fire, resulting in `1440 m ago.` being returned. In fact (once you've fixed the gap issue referred to in the first paragraph), every value is either less-than or greater-than-or-equal-to 60, you'll only ever see seconds or minutes output.

In fact, since the whole `if something return else` construct is redundant (`return` means the `else` is superfluous), you could get away with the simpler:

```
if total_time < 60:
    return str(int(total_time)) + "s ago."
if total_time < 3600:
    return str(int(total_time / 60)) + "m ago."
if total_time < 86400:
    return str(int(total_time / 3600)) + "h ago."
if total_time < 604800:
    return str(int(total_time / 86400)) + "d ago."
return self.date_pub
```

Comment: First off, thanks for helping out with your answer, but I do not understand what you meant by the gaps such as 60. in your first line of your answer.

Comment: @BigMonkey89WithaLeg: set `total_time` to 60 then run that code in your head. It won't match the first `if` condition since it's not `< 60`. It also won't match the first clause in the second `if` condition since it's not `> 60`. You need to use what are called half-open ranges, inclusive at one end but not at the other.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense now

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in the second branch.

When you do 
`elif total_time > 60 or total_time <= 3600:` it will always pass. Since it didn't hit the first branch `total_time is < 60` your time is >=60. Since you have an `or` in your second branch it will always(except for value of 60) pass.

And then the rest of them don't even execute.
You should change the `or's to and's`

Tip: you shouldn't even check for total_time >60. Think of it, what does it mean if the code already got there? First condition failed, therefore you are guaranteed that it will be >= 60.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `and` instead of `or` within your if statement - when it comes into the first or, it knows "yes I'm over 60 seconds", then doesn't care about the other statement because it's already hit a true. Hence, why it always displays in minutes.